# how to do an expo android build for reactnative - without errors

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, eas

I've gotten everything setup from the app to the android studio and gradel.

I run this

```bash
eas build --platform android
```

But I get this error

```
Android build failed
```

and this is the log

```
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 
1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
[stderr] 
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
[stderr] 
   > Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.PivotPoint found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableType found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableVideoView found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScaleManager$1 found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.Size found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4-runtime (com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4)
[stderr] 
     
[stderr] 
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 5m 29s
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
425 actionable tasks: 425 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```